# poetry install не устанавлиает скрипты из tool.poetry.scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, poetry

Пытаюсь написать скрипты в poetry для запуска приложения прямо из cli. При запуске команды **poetry run start-project**, poetry выдает ошибку

`Warning: start-project is an entry point defined in pyproject.toml, but it's not installed as a script.You may get improper sys.argv[0]. The support to run uninstalled scripts will be removed in a future release. Run 'poetry install' to resolve and get rid of this message.No file/folder found for package http-service-processing-files`

Я пытаюсь установить скрипты командой **poetry install**, однако, он лишь пишет, что никаких новых зависимостей не найдено

`Installing dependencies from lock file`

`No dependencies to install or update`

Окружение полностью переустанавливал, также полностью переинициализировал приложение с помощьью **poetry init**. Результата никакого нет.

**Версия poetry: 1.5.1**

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "http-service-processing-files"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
pandas = "^2.0.3"
flask = "^2.3.2"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.4.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
start-project = "src.app:main"
make-test = "src.tests:run_tests"
```

`Дерево директорий`

```
\---http-service-processing-files
    |   .dockerignore
    |   .gitignore
    |   Dockerfile
    |   poetry.lock
    |   pyproject.toml
    |   __init__.py
    |
    +---src
    |   |   app.py
    |   |   tests.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |
    |   +---tests_case
    |   |       test_data.csv
    |   |
    |
    +---templates
    |       index.html
    |       sorted_data.html
    |
```

Пробовал полностью удалять и восстанавливать все зависимости, также реинициализиорвал виртуальное окружение. В конечном счете хочу добиться того, чтобы poetry корректно воспринимал скрипты и появиалсь возможность их исполнения